# Input to store as variable and calculate entire page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it where people can see what they would actually pay vs an estimated cost. I've gone as far as I can with my limited knowledge and I'm not sure where I'm messing up on this.

I have a js fiddle here: [JSFIDDLE!](https://jsfiddle.net/re8sn8sc/4/)

Basically, once a user enters their usage and hits the calculate button, it will turn the Estimated Bill cost into an actual bill cost. I'm pretty new to JS so any help is appreciated!

Quick overview of the code is below, the whole thing is on JSFiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(){
        var newBill = 0;
        var usage = document.addem.tb1.value
     
        $(".content-wrapper.planwrapper").each(function() {
            var originalRate = $(this).find(".v-ratePlanValue").text().replace("¢", "");
            newBill = (parseFloat(originalRate) / 100 * usage + 5.95).toFixed(0);
          $(this).find(".estimatedbill-wrapper .term-description").text("$" + newBill);
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<form name="addem" action="" id="addem" > 
    <p>Enter your kWh here <input type="text" name="tb1"/></p>
    <p>
        <button type="button">Calculate!</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a button on the jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes there is. Let me re-save it real fast.....

Edit: I updated it. Should be good to go!

Comment: Update: I didn't realize JSFiddle created new URLs for new iterations. The link has been corrected

Comment: You haven't include jquery script

Comment: Your code seems fine. I removed all occurrences of script references (specifically your popup code) and included the jQuery dependency and got this: https://jsfiddle.net/re8sn8sc/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is multiple calls of:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.howisthiscalculated').magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Get rid of the copies of it, then it's working.